How can our volunteers record their volunteering activity hours themselves?
We use CiviCRM for managing relationships with donors, volunteers, members, and other stakeholders etc.
I would like to implement something that would allow our volunteers to record the time they spend volunteering for certain activities themselves - I would like them to be able to add some additional information such as notes also and for this info to be recorded within CiviCRM for reporting etc.
Can you recommend a solution that works with CiviCRM?
Thanks in advance.
Regards
Simon

You could just make a new Activity Type for eg Volunteer Hours and then use either Form Builder or https://civicrm.org/extensions/activity-profile to show users a form where they can enter the Duration of their volunteering and use the 'details' field for leaving more info.

Thanks for your answer. Would this allow a volunteer to enter their hours in a separate, standalone form or would they have to login to CiviCRM. Ideally I want something separate - thanks again.

That would mostly depend on the permissions - yes a Profile (and hence I would assume the Activity Profile) can be accessed by anonymous. you would need to ensure that your Matching rule is set up to avoid duplicates or overwriting of existing contacts. You should also be able to send a link with a checksum to the Profile which means existing data would preload for existing contacts
